# Where did I mess up in this program for tracking faction alliances?

Tags: python, list, self

I have a program that models kingdoms and other groups (called 'factions' in my code).

```
class Faction:
    def __init__(self, name, allies=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.allies = allies

    def is_ally_of(self, other_faction):
        if self in other_faction.allies:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def become_ally(self, other_faction, both_ally=True):
        """ If both_ally is false, this does *not* also 
            add self to other_faction's ally list """
        if self.is_ally_of(other_faction):
            print("They're already allies!")
        else:
            self.allies.append(other_faction)
            if both_ally == True:
                other_faction.become_ally(self, False)

RezlaGovt = Faction("Kingdom of Rezla")
AzosGovt = Faction("Azos Ascendancy")
```

I want to be able to call a factions become_ally() method to add factions to the ally lists, like this:

```
RezlaGovt.become_ally(AzosGovt) # Now AzosGovt should be in RezlaGovt.allies,
                                # and RezlaGovt in AzosGovt.allies
```

What actually happens is this:

```
RezlaGovt.become_ally(AzosGovt)
# prints "They're already allies!"
# now AzosGovt is in the allies list of both AzosGovt and RezlaGovt, 
# but RezlaGovt isn't in any allies list at all.
```

Whenever I try to call become_ally(), the code should check to make sure they aren't already allies. This is the part that isn't working. Every time I call become_ally(), it prints "They're already allies!", regardless of if they actually are.

I also tried to use `if self in other_faction.allies:`, but that had the same problem.

I strongly suspect that the problem is with my use of `self`, but I don't know what terms to Google for more information.

Comment: As a side note `if x in y: return True else: return False` can be simplified as `return x in y`

Comment: And `if x == True:` is _usually_ best expressed as `if x:` (which accepts anything truthy, but Pythonic code isn't usually hung up on using `bool` specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't use mutable arguments as the default argument to a function.](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects)

```
def __init__(self, name, allies=[]):
```

When the default is used, it's the *same* `list` each time, so they have the same `allies`; mutating one changes the other because they're actually the same thing.

Change to:

```
def __init__(self, name, allies=None):
   if allies is None:
       allies = []
```

Alternatively, copy the `allies` argument unconditionally (so you're not worried about a reference to it surviving outside the class and getting mutated under the class):

```
def __init__(self, name, allies=[]):
    self.allies = list(allies)  # Which also guarantees a tuple argument becomes list
                                # and non-iterable args are rejected
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this function.

```
def is_ally_of(self, other_faction):
        if other_faction in self.allies:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Check your own data not that of the passed in object.

Also

```
def __init__(self, name, allies=[]):
```

Is a bug waiting to happen. Your `allies` list will be a static list shared between all instances. Instead use

```
def __init__(self, name, allies=None):
        self.name = name
        self.allies = allies or []
```

Comment: The first suggestion is not actually a problem depending on precise design goals (the phrasing is problematic; usually, allies is a mutual thing so it can't be one way, but this code allows one way alliances).

Comment: Yes, I did design it to allow one-way alliances, in case one nation secretly declares war without the other nation knowing, or some other strange situation that might require it.

Comment: The function is probably better named `is_ally`. There is a mixing up of intent in your `become_ally` function. It has logic saying if I'm not an ally of X then add X to my ally list, whereas it should probably be more like, if X is not my ally add X to my list of allies.